# Is it possible to enumerate strings as integers for a fast comparison? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, enumeration

I need to enumerate 3 `NSString` as `integers` in a way that it would be easy to compare two numbers and find out which is the lower one. The 3 strings are:

```
@"verde" = 1
@"giallo" = 2
@"rosso" = 3
```

and it should be compared against an other integer in an `if statement`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you are trying to achieve here. Are these strings the keys in a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but... an enum could help you?

Comment: No strings are not in a dictionary, I just want to assign to the "verde", "giallo" and "rosso" string values the numbers: 1 2 and 3 to compare them, since you can compare a string to a number

Comment: @Zil How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand, but this might be what you want.  Keep a dictionary of the string to integer mapping:

```
NSDictionary *stringMap = @{
    @"verde": @(1),
    @"giallo": @(2),
    @"rosso": @(3)
};
```

and when it comes to the comparison, do:

```
NSString *s1 = @"verde";
NSString *s2 = @"rosso";
NSNumber *n1 = stringMap[s1];
NSNumber *n2 = stringMap[s2];
if (n1 && n2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [n1 compare n2];
    if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // s1 < s2
    } else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
        // s1 > s2
    } else {
        // s1 == s2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You sound like in need for `enum`. Try this out:

**Step 1 :** Define an enum like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, MyStrings) {
    Verde = 0,
    Giallo,
    Rosso
};
```

**Step 2 :** Define an enum type property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MyStrings string;
```

**Step 3 :** Finally use it like this:

```
self.string = 2; // Setting property value

if (self.string < Verde) {
    NSLog(@"Small Value");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Big Value");
}
```